# Как в php в параметр header прокинуть UTM-метки?

Tags: php, html, header

есть php обработчик формы, который принимает через request метки с лендинга, нужно эти метки передать на success.html конструктора (где нельзя активировать сессию и подтянуть метки из сессии)

После обработки order.php с помощью header перенаправляет пользователя на страницу success

> header('Location: [https://my-site.com/success?СЮДАНАДОКАК-ТОПРОПИСАТЬ](https://my-site.com/success?%D0%A1%D0%AE%D0%94%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9A-%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%9F%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC) МЕТКИ')

Comment: Сложно( ПАМАГИТЕ

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, нужно просто использовать конкатенацию строк.

```
$q = $_REQUEST['q'];
$w = $_REQUEST['w'];
$e = $_REQUEST['e'];

header('Location: https://my-site.com/success?q='.$q.'&w='.$w.'&e='.$e.'')
```

Если по простому, то мы просто складываем эти строки в одну и перенаправляем пользователя.